# filter django formset table in jQuery based on selected option asynchronously

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am trying to implement filter buttons in my django formset and found a solution that would allow user to do that asynchronously.

I tried to use code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/2/) but my html is more complex and I don't know how to filter each row based on text in Product column.

My problem is that I am not sure how to pass related_product name as value or as text in jQuery function so when I select test product it will show me only rows that contain *"test product*" text:

[image]

So what should I put as class name in `$('tbody tr').show();` to get related_product title and show all rows that contains this related_product title?

views.py

```
class ProductComponentView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "formset.html"
    
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_components = CostCalculator.objects.all()
        get_datetime = timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        product_list = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
        
        formset = RequestFormset(initial=[{
            'author': self.request.user.email,
            'related_product': component.related_product,
            'related_component': component.id,
            'created': get_datetime,
            'number_of_units': 0
            } for component in get_components])

        return self.render_to_response(
            {'product_component_formset': formset, 
            'product_list': product_list,
            })

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):

        formset = RequestFormset(data=self.request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                form.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

formset.html

```
{% for product in product_list %}
  <input class="filterbox" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="{{product.title}}" />{{product.title}}<br />
{% endfor %}

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <table class="table table-hover" style="border-color: 1px solid black !important;">
      {{ product_component_formset.management_form }}
      <thead>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Component</th>
          <th>Number of units</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {% for form in product_component_formset.forms %}
          <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row hidden tags test-" style="border-color: black">
              {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
              <td>
                  {% if forloop.first %}
                      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                          {{ hidden }}
                      {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
                  {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                  {{ field }}
              </td>
              {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
  </table>
      <button class="cost-calculator" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    
{% block javascript_files %}

<script>
  $('input').click( function() {
    $('.tags').hide();
    $('input:checked').each( function(i) {
        $('tbody tr').show();
    });
});
</script>

{% endblock javascript_files %}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show html generated for tr tags ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a script like this could help?

Edit: this do update the html only, if you are using some sort of automated form submiting all rows data, you may want to filter by only those being shown, for example using a css class to declare wheter or not a row is aviable to submition.

```js
$('.tags').hide();
$('.control').find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){        
          $('input:checkbox').each( function() {
              checked = $(this).prop('checked');
              if(checked) $('div#' + $(this).val()).show();
              else $('div#' + $(this).val()).hide();
          });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
<input type="checkbox" value="generated_1"> <label>show/hide generated_1 </label>
<input type="checkbox" value="generated_2"> <label>show/hide generated_2 </label>
<input type="checkbox" value="generated_3"> <label>show/hide generated_3 </label>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="tags" id="generated_1">Generated row 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
  <div class="tags" id="generated_2">Generated row 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
  <div class="tags" id="generated_3">Generated row 3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In django it would be something like this:

```
{% for item in list %}
//if statement to prevent not desired filter checkboxes being generated

<input type="checkbox" value="{{item.field_name_for_example}}"> <label>show/hide {{item.field_name_for_example}}</label>
{% endfor %}

<ul>
{% for item in list %}
  <li>
    <div class="tags" id="{{item.field_name_for_example}}">Generated row 1</div>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer however I cannot change my template file. It must be a formset in tabular form where user is able to insert number of units per component in each product that (s)he selects

Comment: You know, i didn't mean to say that the solution was to copy and paste my answer. My actual answer is just the id="{{item.field_name_for_example}}" in the rows, id="{{item.field_name_for_example}}" in the checkboxes and the jquery script. I don't see why that can't fit with in your template but sure enough if you say so.